# Handle closing event of a webview

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

Is there a way to know on user closing a web view and cancel close if needed?
I need to do validation of data in the web view and prompt user to save changes if there are unsaved changes.

I could find only two events on the WebviewPanel - onDidDispose and onDidChangeViewState.
These do not seem to help. Is there another way to handle close event and prevent or show a confirmation dialog before allowing the web view to close?